# Polarization type/direction of $E$ field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, polarization

I have an E field given as $E(z) = [xE_a - yjE_b]\exp(-jkz)$ and I know the answer is that the field is right-hand circularly/elliptically polarized depending on whether $E_a = E_b$. Can someone show me how I can prove this? I have a midterm tomorrow and it's on the review sheet, but I don't know what to do. All I know is that I need to convert it to the instantaneous form.

edit: this isn't supposed to be turned in or graded it's just to go over concepts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a mathematical definition of the circular polarization. According to the definition it is the sum of two plane waves with orthogonal polarizations being shifted relative each others by some phase. If you will figure out what that phase is you may found it in your formula.

Comment: figured it out, I wasn't understanding that I needed to change the -jy to +yexp(-j*pi/2) before I do the Re{E*exp(jwt)}.